# Instagram API limit using multiple access tokens from the same IP?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

EDIT 22/11/2019:
This question should probably be considered outdated now seeing as Instagram have made some major changes limiting their API since the time I originally asked this question.

---

I am creating a web app which makes automated calls to Instagram API on behalf of each user registered with the app (the app will generate and store the access token of each user upon registration as part of authenticating with the user's IG account).

Instagram's official API documentation states 
on [this page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/) that the Global Rate limits per access token are 5000 per hour when the app is live.

Hypothetically, if the app has 100 users registered and authenticated with Instagram,

1. Would it be possible to make up to 5000 requests on behalf of every user through each access token in one hour, considering that this would still be  up to 500k requests made in one hour from a single IP address (the backend server)?
2. Am I allowed to make requests from multiple access tokens concurrently in this way?
3. Are there limits for single IP addresses / simultaneous sessions?

I have tried to find the request limit for Instagram API for a single IP address, to no avail. All information about rate limits that I've found so far is per access token (or client id), so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make 5000 calls per token, so 500k

There is no limit per IP or session as far as I know.